# How do you add a featured image to a page (not post)?

Tags: pages, post-thumbnails, blog-page

There's no "add featured image" in the settings section in a page I created. On the other hand, a similar blogpost I created has this setting. I went over some websites which told me that I needed to enable it in screen options for it to be displayed in the settings, but that didn't work either. Please help me out (I am not coding in PHP or CSS, just using the wordpress editor to create my website).[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can enable featured image for pages (and other post types) by using the line below. This goes in your `functions.php` file.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
```

If you're not comfortable with editing theme files then you should contact your theme developer. If featured images are not enabled by default in your theme they have to be enabled first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am able to add featured images for blogposts, but not pages. Is this a problem specific to some themes or is this how it is? Also I am using the wordpress editor and not coding, so do you have a way for me to do the same without coding?

Comment: If you're not comfortable with editing theme files then you should contact your theme developer.

Comment: @Rakshith Also, in future please note that this site is intended for development and coding questions. For user support you should try the WordPress support forums, or the support channels of theme and plugin authors.